# Creating functions in a list

Tags: python, lambda, binding

I have noticed that this construction

```
funcs = [lambda x: x**n for n in range(5)]
```

fails to produce the expected results, e.g.

```
[f(0.5) for f in funcs]
# [0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625]
```

What is the canonical solution to this problem? I have my own workaround, which is this pattern

```
def function_maker(n):
    return lambda x: x**n

funcs = [function_maker(n) for n in range(5)]
[f(0.5) for f in funcs]
# [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]
```

I wondered whether this was a good idea. Could it in more complicated cases hide further nasty surprises?

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty canonical as you need to create a closure over `n` to retain the value.
You can do it as a one liner but it is ugly:

```
>>> funcs = [(lambda e: lambda x: x**e)(n) for n in range(5)]
>>> [f(0.5) for f in funcs]
[1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]
```

Comment: Ah OK. This is my `function_maker` in a lambda expression?

Comment: @innisfree Yes. Although it would be cleaner to just use a function.